# I have just done this same code but not getting exact time as per Indian timezone...What thing should I add to get exact time?

Tags: arduino-mega

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample sketch demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/

static const int RXPin = 10, TXPin = 11;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
  Serial.println(F("DeviceExample.ino"));
  Serial.println(F("A simple demonstration of TinyGPS++ with an attached GPS module"));
  Serial.print(F("Testing TinyGPS++ library v. ")); Serial.println(TinyGPSPlus::libraryVersion());
  Serial.println(F("by Mikal Hart"));
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0)
    if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
      displayInfo();
  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10) {
    Serial.println(F("No GPS detected: check wiring."));
    while(true);
  }
}

void displayInfo() {
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (gps.location.isValid()) {
    Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
    Serial.print(F(","));
    Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date/Time: "));
  if (gps.date.isValid()) {
    Serial.print(gps.date.month());
    Serial.print(F("/"));
    Serial.print(gps.date.day());
    Serial.print(F("/"));
    Serial.print(gps.date.year());
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F(" "));
  if (gps.time.isValid()) {
    if (gps.time.hour() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.hour());
    Serial.print(F(":"));
    if (gps.time.minute() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.minute());
    Serial.print(F(":"));
    if (gps.time.second() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.second());
    Serial.print(F("."));
    if (gps.time.centisecond() < 10) Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.print(gps.time.centisecond());
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=473294.msg3237680#msg3237680

Answer (score 1):

Use NeoGPS instead of TinyGPS, it has time and date functions for timezone offsets.

Ref:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=473294.msg3237680#msg3237680

Comment: This is a link-only answer, please provide the relevant parts in the answer here.

Comment: @Avamander changed the answer as requested.

Comment: Thank you, at least it won't be flagged as "link-only" now.